# Enhance is_valid() with an exception

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a django charField that is checked via the is_valid() method. The user is supposed to enter a valid logical expression in this field, so I wrote a parsing method that raises an exception if the expression is not correct.

How can I enhance the is_valid() method to cover this exception and display an error message to the user that his query was wrong?

I read this article (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) but still have no idea how to do that.

```
        try:
        job = Job(user=request.user)  # set the current user
        form = JobForm(request.POST, instance=job)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            job.execute()
            messages.success(request, u'A new job with the query "{query}" was created.'.format(query=job.query))
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('job-index'))

        return self.render_to_response({'job_form': form, 'is_new': True})
    except ParseError:
        return self.render_to_response({'job_form': form, 'is_new': True})
```

The try...except-Block should be done within the is_valid() method, that is my intention. Someone got any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've provided an answer to the question yourself - you [create your own form (or model form)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#form-objects) and [perform custom validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) on that form's field using its `clean_'fieldname'()` method. So for example, say your model is:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    expression_field = models.CharField(...)
    ...
```

you create a `forms.py`:

```
class JobForm(forms.ModelForm):
    pass
    class Meta:
        model = Job 

    def clean_expression_field(self):
         # You perform your custom validation on this field in here, 
         # raising any problems
         value = self.cleaned_data['expression_field']
         if value is 'really_bad':
              raise forms.ValidationError("bad bad bad")
         return value
```

then make use of it in your `views.py` as you already are in your example. Now if the value the user enters doesn't meet your criteria, an exception will be automatically raised

Comment: I was writing a very similar answer when yours came in. Well said!